# Issue with Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, logstash, reverse-proxy, kibana

we have a nginx server running Kibana on 80.
We have also setup Kibana for our staging environments.
So if we hit https://mykibana.mycompany.com/staging it should hit
staging kibana server listening on 80.

We tried all sorts of configurations to set this reverse proxy, but its not working.
https://mykibana.mycompany.com/staging returns "Not Found"

Here is my config:
`upstream staging_hosts {
    server XX.YY.ZZ.WW;
}`

`location @staging {
         proxy_pass http://staging_hosts;
         }`

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why `@staging` rather than `/staging`? Also, shouldn't the server declaration in the upstream directive specify the Kibana port number?

Comment: try removing the schema part ("http://") in the proxy pass as you are dealing with https traffic or create a separate upstream for http and include the port on server XX.YY.ZZ.WW:80;

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My new config looks like this now and it works.
`location /staging/ {
                  rewrite /staging http://XX.YY.ZZ.WW:5601 last;
         }`

but the problem here is, once the URL is redirected to /staging. It exposes the IP XX.YY.ZZ.WW, which is bad. Any other way I can mask it and just make it looks like https://mykibana.mycompany.com/staging

Comment: Then use  proxy_pass (with the port) instead of rewrite.